# how to updated table with dynamic data in where conditioner in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to Updated view  using this query :

```
  UPDATE tableview SET status = 1 where event_id in (SELECT eventsId
    FROM tableview2 where status <>1)
```

using this Query i am getting 1,2,3,4

```
 SELECT eventsId
        FROM tableview2 where status <>1
```

but when i try to Updated it show more than one column operand please suggest me how to Updated it

Comment: you can do inner join instead on making subquery.That will help you.Show your data i ll create query for you

Comment: Add sample table data, before and after update versions (as well formatted text.) Show us the view definition.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/SWTDRhtVv25YzrzChh8WxX  check it @AnkitAgrawal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work for you

```
  UPDATE tableview v1
    inner join  tableview2 v2 on v1.event_id =v2.event_id
    SET status = 1 
    where v2.status<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableview SET status = 1 
FROM tableview2 v2 
WHERE tableview.event_id = v2.event_id AND v2.status<>1
```